# How To Store Text Diffs in DB?

Tags: php, mysql, diff

I have already decided on using the Horde Text_Diff engine in a LAMP stack for calculating diff's and rendering them. My question is this:

What would be a good way of actually storing the incrementals in a database? I've never had to design this kind of database application before, and it appears that most engines want a fully serialized copy of the entire original and changed text in order to render the differences.

If that's the case, then how can I store the data of the diff in a database without storing the entire new document?

(NOTE: For this particular purpose, it will always be current version->proposed diff->new current version, meaning that I'm trying to store an actual diff instead of a reverse diff.)

Comment: Also note, this means I will never have to do a three-way diff or merge two diffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to work with the [`patch` utility](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch). It creates the difference between two texts (or files) in form of the changes only. That created patch can then be stored inside the database. You still need the original text and then all patches up to the latest revision.

For PHP the [**xdiff Extension**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.xdiff.php) can be used for creating diffs for text and files.

### Storing DIFFs in the database

To store the diffs inside the database you need to preserve the order of diffs, the diffs contents and the original text.

I assume you are already storing the original text. The diffs then can be stored into a diffs table containing a reference to the original text and and auto-increment key to preserve the order next to the text-contents of the diffs. You then need to insert one diff after the other in the correct order and should be fine.

To recreate the current version, query the original version and all diffs ordered. Then apply one diff after the other to get the version you like to get.

Alternatively you can create another table that contains a specific revisions result as well so to prevent to run lot of cycles over and over again. But then this will make the data inside the database redundant.

Comment: So this method would instead use the Linux command line to create a patch file using diff, and apply it using patch?

Comment: This answer the question "how to generate diffs", which was not asked.

Comment: I'm fine with generating the diffs... there's dozens of solutions for that, I just see no way to recombine them, unless I guess I use the command line like you're positing. What I'm really looking for is a way to CREATE a patch file from an arbitrary diff engine. (NOTE: I'm seeking a method, not necessarily code that already does this.)

Comment: @JRL: I added some sort of how this could be stored inside the DB (as you asked for it). However reading your last comment I still have a problem to fully understand your problem. Probably it's already part of the edit, if not, leave some more comment on what's missing. Probably there is some easy way to find out.

Comment: hakre: the main issue is that the rendering engine in Horde is expecting a Text_Diff object in PHP, which requires a serialized array. I can just store the diff lines in the db, I'm just not sure how the program would even understand what those diffs represent, or what format it expects them to be stored in.

Comment: xdiff requires a lot of server work for me, but it accomplishes what I'm looking for: a string I can store in the database that can later be rendered with the original to show the complete updated version.

Answer (score 4):

For Wiki applications, consider storing:

1. Full text of the most recent edition [to facilitate e.g. searching, rapid display], e.g in a table "articles"
2. Older editions as reverse diffs of the most recent text.  Each prior edition could be stored as `StoredEdition[X] = diff(Edition[X+1], Edition[X])`, where `Edition[0]` is the oldest.  E.g. in a table "articles_revisions", with each row having a timestamp and referring to articleID.

Sorry, at this moment I don't have a suggestion for tools to reconstitute text from serial diffs or reverse-diffs.